# Automation tool for Firefox that can manipulate User-Agent or Referrer?

Tags: greasemonkey, user-agent, referrer, imacros, chickenfoot

I need to automate some processes in Firefox via Chickenfoot, Greasemonkey, iMacros or any other automation tool. Is any of them allows to change the browser's User-Agent or Referer/Referrer fields?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I see people mention to use one of the many Firefox plugins to control Referrer. But the problem is that most of the addons allow to set the referrer manually in the beginning of the session. I need the referrer to be changing many time during the automation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greasemonkey will let you specify a user agent when you use the [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) function, but it won't let you change referrer.

Some Firefox extensions that will probably do what you want:

1. [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)
2. [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/)

Comment: Can I then dynamically change the referrer from the automation script by supplying a new referrer URL to one of these plugins?

Comment: Did a little research on RefControl and found out that it allows to use some variables when constructing the referrer string. It actually solved my problem. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you might be able to leverage User Agent Switcher, which is an awesome extension (add on) for doing this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/